# What should be the size of input image for training a YOLOv3 Model Architecture CNN.?

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, yolo, conv-neural-network

I've implemented a YOLOv3 from scratch and I plan to fine-tune using MS-COCO weights for some different data.
The dataset I've chosen has images of 720*1280 size.

When I go through the YOLOv3 paper, 1st CONV2d layer is there with filter_size =3 and stride = 1, and output size is 256*256....

Can someone give me a walkthrough for how YOLO training part works in here?

Answer (score 2):

From [Yolov3](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLOv3.pdf) paper:

- If best possible accuracy/mAP is what you want then use `608 x 608` as input layer size in the [config](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg).
- If you want good inference/speed at the cost of accuracy then use, `320 x 320`
- If balanced model is what you want then use `416 x 416`

Note that first layer automatically resizes your images to the size of first layer in `Yolov3` CNN, so you need not convert your `1280 x 720` images to the input layer size.

Suggest you to read following things:

- To understand how Yolov3 works, read this [blog](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088) post.
- To understand some basic stuff read from original [site](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/)
- Learn how to train your custom object detector [here](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/)